# Contact form in PHP: Allowing the user to send me an email

Tags: php, email

On my website I have a contact form, where the user can report bugs or submit feature requests. The form contains a *subject* and *message*.

I want the form to email me directly, either with PHPMailer or with PHP's built-in mail function.

The issue here is when generating the email, the *sender* has to be an address I own, not the actual user's email address. The reason for this is obvious, since we shouldn't be allowed to impersonate other people. However I want to be able to email my users back directly from my inbox, which I can't do since I can't use their address to email myself in the script.

What is the best way to construct the contact form then?
The only workaround I can think of is to insert the message + sender address into a database, and then read it manually from there....an epic hassle.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `Reply-To` e-mail header, so you'll get something like this:

```
<?php
$headers = 'From: you@example.com' . "\r\n";
// Set the sender address as Reply-to below
$headers .= 'Reply-To: sender@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail('you@example.com', 'Subject here', 'The message goes here', $headers);
?>
```

This way you will be the sender, but when you hit the reply button in your mail client, it will default to reply to the address listed in the `Reply-To` header.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the center have to be an address you own?

SMTP won't prohibit you from providing the email your user provides as the sender.  As long as the SMTP server allows you to relay from it, it will take any value for sender and recipient.

Another option would be to make a sender email up (contact-form@yourdomain.com) and set the Reply-To field to your user's email address.

Comment: If the sender's domain has [Sender Policy Framework](http://www.openspf.org/) enabled, the mail won't arrive as your web server is not listed in the SPF record of their domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to receive an email from an address you own but when you reply it'll go to the user's email

```
<?php
$to      = 'youremail@yourdomain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'message';
$headers = 'From: youremail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: user@useremail.com' . "\r\n" .
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: That's like an exact duplicate of what I said 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Maybe he was writing it for 5 minutes :P